# Getting the following error "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm getting the below errors when I'm trying to add a `ListView` widget as a child to a `Column`. I did check out few solutions, but couldn't get it worked out.

I have copied excerpts from the error.

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#c4e1c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib/screens/app_home.dart:51
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The `ListView` is getting built by a `StreamBuilder` below is the code for the same.

```
final coursesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses').limit(10).where('courseLive', isEqualTo: true);

class CourseStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: coursesCollection.snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: kBrandColor),
            );
          }
        }

        final courseListStream = snapshot.data!.docs.map((course) {
          return CourseData.fromDocument(course);
        }).toList();

        List<BadgedCourseCard> courseCards = [];

        for (var course in courseListStream) {
          final courseDocID = course.courseDocID;
          final courseID = course.courseID;
          final courseTitle = course.courseTitle;
          final courseDescription = course.courseDescription;
          final courseSubTitle = course.courseSubTitle;
          final courseBadge = course.courseBadge;
          final courseLevel = course.courseLevel;
          final coursePaid = course.coursePaid;
          final courseImage = course.courseImage;
          final courseBgColor = hexToColor(course.courseBackgroundColor.toString());
          final courseBgColor1 = hexToColor(course.courseBgColor1.toString());
          final courseBgColor2 = hexToColor(course.courseBgColor2.toString());
          final courseFgColor = hexToColor(course.courseFgColor.toString());
          final courseDeliveryFormat = course.courseDeliveryFormat;
          final courseLive = course.courseLive;

          final badgedCourseCard = BadgedCourseCard(
            courseTitle: courseTitle.toString(),
            courseTitleTextColor: courseFgColor,
            cardBackgroundColor: courseBgColor,
            courseImage: courseImage.toString(),
            courseCardTapped: () => print("Course Card Tapped"),
            courseBookmarkTapped: () => print("Course Bookmark Tapped"),
          );

        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: courseCards,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Listed below is the code where I'm trying to consume the `CourseStream` class. This is where the error is getting triggered.

```
class AppHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppHomeState createState() => _AppHomeState();
}

class _AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // drawer: AppDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.5.w),
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(ScaledAnimationPageRoute(AppDrawer())),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.sort,
              color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
              size: 6.5.w,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.5.w),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                size: 6.5.w,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CardHeader(
                leadingText: "Courses",
                trailingText: "View All",
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 1.h),
              CourseStream(),
              SizedBox(height: 2.h),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you need any further details, please do let me know.

Really appreciate, if anyone could help me in getting this issue fixed. Thanks a lot in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your Column is positioned inside a SingleChildScrollView, which has unbounded size, but contains an `Expanded` widget (`CourseStream`), which tries to take up as much size as possible. Basically the Expanded widget doesn't know when to stop expanding.

As far as how to help you achieve what you're trying to do, I'm not quite clear on what the desired behavior is, but essentially you'll need to define the height of your list items.

It seems like you might be trying to achieve a paging effect - if that's the case, then you might find the PageView widget helpful: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Similar to `CourseStream` I would be having multiple children added to the `Column` widget and these children would overflow the screen that's the reason I'm making use of `SingleChildScrollView` as a parent to the `Column` widget to prevent this overflow. Most of the children of the `Column` would be `ListView`s, that would scroll in horizontal axis again to prevent them from getting overflowed. If I remove the `SingleChildScrollView` the children of the `Column` would throw `bottom overflow error` not sure what to do?

Comment: Is there perhaps a screenshot, or even video of the layout you're trying to achieve? It would be helpful to have a clear idea of the end result

Comment: Let me see, if I can capture a video and share it across.

Comment: In simple words all I can say is. I want the `Column` to be vertically scrollable and most of its `children` to be horizontally scrollable. The reason I need this vertical and horizontal scrolling is to prevent the `Column' from throwing a `bottom overflow` error and its `children` from throwing a `right overflow` error. Hope this simplifies what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that part - I was more trying to find out what you're trying to achieve by wrapping your `CourseStream` in `Expanded` since that's what's causing the error - Knowing that, I may be able to suggest an alternative way to achieve the layout you're going for

Comment: You're are most welcome. I just saw it somewhere they had wrapped the `ListView` in an `Expanded` widget that's the reason I did it.

Comment: I have added the screenshots @Michael Horn hope this helps in understanding what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: I did remove the `SingleChildScrollView` it fixed this problem but presented with another problem. Will you be able help me in fixing this issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

I did wrap the `ListView` with a `SizedBox` widget this fixed the issue.

```
return SizedBox(
       height: 20.5.h,
       child: ListView(
         physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         children: courseCards,
      ),
);
```